# How to draw a dotted circle with StageXL in Dart

Tags: canvas, dart, stagexl

I am trying to draw a circle with a dotted border. I've tried this:

```dart
Shape shape = new Shape()
..graphics.beginPath()
            ..graphics.circle( 50 , 50, 50 )
            ..graphics.closePath()
            ..graphics.strokePattern(new GraphicsPattern.repeat(new BitmapData.fromImageElement(new HTML.ImageElement(src: "img/dash.png"))))
            ..addTo(stage);
    }
```

But the circle does not get displayed. It seems that the strokePattern line breaks my code. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution.:

```dart
void _addDottedCircle(double x, double y, int radius) {
    List<double> xCoords = new List<double>();
    List<double> yCoords = new List<double>();

    for (int i = 0; i < radius; i++) {
        xCoords.add( radius * cos(2 * PI * i / radius) + x);
        yCoords.add( radius * sin(2 * PI * i / radius) + y);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < radius; i++) {
        new Shape()
            ..graphics.beginPath()
            ..graphics.circle(xCoords[i], yCoords[i], 1)
            ..graphics.closePath()
            ..graphics.fillColor(lightgreen)
            ..addTo(stage);
    }
}
```